# How do i make an SQL statement display a name starting with certain characters without using the LIKE function

Tags: ms-access

I tried this code to display names starting with J, S, or M without using operator.

but it gives one problem, it is wrong statement since it isn't about first character in the name, its showing results of names with the characters anywhere in the name.

How do I fix this?

````
FROM Student
WHERE InStr(Stud_name, "J") OR InStr(Stud_name, "S") OR InStr(Stud_name, "M");```
````

Comment: I do not know MS Access and its available functions, but I guess you can try to find something like LEFT(Stud_name,1)='J'

Comment: `LIKE` is an operator, not a function, however, why don't you want to use it? `LIKE` seems to be exactly the right operator here.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you do not want to use the exact operator that is designed for what you want to do?

Comment: @Sergey Thanks so much that is perfect

Comment: `InStr()` returns the position of the first occurrence of the search string e.g. `InStr("test", "e")` returns 2, so you could check by using `InStr(Stud_name, "J") = 1` to check if it is the first letter. Or for multiple checks you could use:  `1 IN (InStr(Stud_name, "J"), InStr(Stud_name, "S"), InStr(Stud_name, "M"))`

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. `Left(Stud_name, 1) = "J" OR InStr(Stud_name, 1) = "S" OR InStr(Stud_name, 1) = "M"`
2. `InStr(Stud_name, "J") = 1 OR InStr(Stud_name, "S") = 1 OR InStr(Stud_name, "M") = 1`
3. `Left(Stud_name, 1) IN ("J", "S", "M")`